# symfony2 oci connect doctrine

Tags: oracle, apache, symfony, doctrine

I have configure Oci & PHP and runs correctly. When I run php file for connect to Oracle using php works fine.
When I run php app/console doctrine:mapping:import, the entities are discovered and the entity file exists with the table's fields, but when I try to browser to http://localhost/app_dev.php shows me:

```
 DEBUG - oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set and point to the right directories DEBUG - oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804 CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occured in driver: " at /var/www/html/proyecto3/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractOracleDriver.php line 76
```

My configuration files are:

config.yml

```
> doctrine:
>     dbal:
>         driver:   oci8   
>         host:     "%database_host%"
>         port:     "%database_port%"
>         dbname:   "%database_name%"
>         user:     "%database_user%"
>         password: "%database_password%"
>         charset:  UTF8
```

parameters.yml

```
> parameters:
>     database_host: 192.168.59.148
>     database_port: 1521
>     database_name: BRULO001
>     database_user: scott
>     database_password: scott
>     mailer_transport: smtp
>     mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
>     mailer_user: null
>     mailer_password: null
```

I try to set vars ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside /etc/sysconfig/httpd and httpd.conf files, but not works

Comment: ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are env constants. Take a look at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable

Comment: What are the values of environment variables `TZ` and `ORA_SDTZ` ?